# Javascript getComputedStyle - copy object without reference

Tags: javascript

I want to change the color of an input field border. But yet before changing, I need to save the initial CSS via getComputedStyle so that I can set all the initial CSS of the input field back.
The problem is that the object of getComputedStyle is not fixed and changes dynamically.

I tried to copy the object into a new one without reference, but then I cannot use the property getPropertyValue because it is a different type of object.
Is there any way how I could retrieve back the initial CSS of the input field?

My code is the following:

```js
const input_element = document.getElementById('text-id');
let computedStyle_fixed;

function change_color() {
  // get computed style
  const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(input_element);
  // copy computed style into new object without reference
  computedStyle_fixed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(computedStyle));
  // change the border color of the input field
  input_element.style.borderColor = 'red';
}

function retrieve_color() {
  Array.from(computedStyle_fixed).forEach(
    key => element.style.setProperty(key, computedStyle_fixed.getPropertyValue(key), 'important')
  )
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='text-id'>
<button onclick='change_color()'>Change color</button>
<button onclick='retrieve_color()'>Retrieve color</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

from what I understood is that you need all the css properties of a element and store in an object.

you can use spread operator to do so.

```
const computedStyle = {...window.getComputedStyle(input_element)};
```

you can now use this like a normal object.

ex : `console.log(computedStyle.backgroundColor);`

Comment: Yes, this is the easist way. That is solved. Wouldn't you know how to get the exactly same style as initialy, pls. see my answer with the jsfiddle link.

Comment: if you want specific stylings to be applied then you can just do it manually else you can loop through the keys of the object and set all the styles....in my opinion looping through everything might cause performance issues

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues in your code. Firstly in this line:

```
const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(input_element);
```

[*window.getComputedStyle*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) returns a [*CSSStyleDeclaration* object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration). When copied using:

```
computedStyle_fixed = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(computedStyle));
```

the object assigned to *computedStyle_fixed* is a plain object, not a *CSSStyleDeclaration* object. This has consequences in the *retrieve_color* function explained further down.

Then in:

```
Array.from(computedStyle_fixed)
```

[*Array.from*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) expects the argument to be an array–like object with a *length* property or an iterable object. *computedStyle_fixed* is neither so the result is an empty array and the following *forEach* does nothing (because length is 0).

Within the *forEach* callback, there is:

```
computedStyle_fixed.getPropertyValue(key)
```

the *computedStyle_fixed* object doesn't have a *getPropertyValue* method (see above), so if that line is executed the result will be a type error.

To iterate the properties of the *computedStyle_fixed* object, use [*Object.keys*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and access properties using square bracket notation, not the (missing) *getPropertyValue* method, e.g.

```
Object.keys(computedStyle_fixed).forEach(key => 
   element.style.setProperty(key, computedStyle_fixed[key], 'important')
);
```

**Other notes**

Creating implicit globals like *computedStyle_fixed* is not recommended, declare them or set them as object properties.

Using *JSON.stringify* to create a shallow copy of an object is also not a good idea, it's much better to use [*Object.assign*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
let computedStyle_fixed = Object.assign({}, computedStyle);
```

This also creates a plain object, not a *CSSStyleDeclaration* object.

Comment: Thank you, finally it occured to me too and I changed it in similar way. I know creating implicit globals is not good, I made this issue as a quick example. Nevertheless I didn't get the same result as I expected, see my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, I have just change a little the retrieve_color() function.
But I thought that it would set the style of the input border exactly as it used to be initialy.
If you look at the code at jsfiddle and click on change_color and then click on retrieve_color, you will see that the input does not look as it was (the border are different).
Do you have any idea how I could get it back exactly as it was?

```
// the code    
https://jsfiddle.net/gfxjn4se/
```